# Polymer data binding does not work

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to get the `<core-menu>` working with Dart. It displays fine but the `selectedIndex` property is not updated. 
The following code works fine with PolymerJS but in the Dart version the `selectedIndex` is not updated (`<core-menu selectedIndex="{{selectedMenuIndex}}"...>`)

I would expect the `{{selectedMenuIndex}}` to be available in the `<core-animated-pages>` tag but the `{{selectedMenuIndex}}` variable is empty. It does not get updated. The `.dart` file has the var declared as this:

```dart
@observable num selectedMenuIndex = 0;
```

This is the .html code:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_drawer_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_item.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_icon_button.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_icon_button.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_header_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/core_animated_pages.html">

<polymer-element name="test-app">

<template>
<!-- [START html] -->
<core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">

    <core-header-panel drawer>
        <core-toolbar id="navheader'">
            <span>Menu</span>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-menu selected="0" selectedIndex="{{selectedMenuIndex}}" id="coreMenu" on-click="{{togglePanelButton}}">
            <core-item icon="settings" label="One"></core-item>
            <core-item icon="search" label="Two"></core-item>
        </core-menu>
    </core-header-panel>

    <core-header-panel main>
        <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
            <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu" on-click="{{ togglePanelButton }}"></paper-icon-button>
            <span flex>Title</span>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-animated-pages selected="{{selectedMenuIndex}}" notap id="core_animated_pages" transitions="slide-from-right">
            <section class="content-section">
                Section 1
            </section>
            <section class="content-section">
                Section 2
            </section>
        </core-animated-pages>
    </core-header-panel>

</core-drawer-panel>
<!-- [END html]-->
</template>

<script type="application/dart" src="testapp.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Are you guys having problems with databing as well or is it me that does something wrong?

UPDATE: I have filed a bug report for it here:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19794

Comment: This usually works in Polymer.dart. This is either an issue in core_elements (which are in experimental state currently) or a bug I encountered recently when you assign an initial value to your observable field (see also my comment on the lined bug report).

Comment: Thanks. By using the standard DOM elements like <input instead if <core-* it works. So yes, this is an issue with core_elements. Just waiting for the guys to fix.

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed. See the above linked issue or my updated answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from the Dart Polymer group here:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19794

Seems there is an issue with the 2-way binding with the core_elements.

Comment: Reading through that thread helped me to resolve this issue as well. I had the wrong version in my pubspec

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.  When I tried to embed core-elements in a custom polymer element the core-element wouldn't load.  I moved the core-element to the index.html file and it worked.

I see that there is a patch to address this. The patch suggests that when compiled to JS the code should work.  I haven't had luck in JS.