# Databinding of polymer paper_input does not work

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design, paper-elements

I have the following code where a 2-way binding is expected between first_name and the property val.

```dart
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

  <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html" >

  <polymer-element name='paper-input-snippet'>
    <template>

    <div on-mouseout="{{zoom}}">
      <paper-input
        label="First" floatinglabel
        error="Invalid input"

        id="first_name"
        value='{{val}}'>
      </paper-input>

      <paper-input
        label="Middle" floatinglabel
        error="Invalid input"

        id="middle_name">
      </paper-input>

      <paper-input
        label="Last" floatinglabel
        error="Invalid input"

        id="last_name">
      </paper-input>

    </div>

    </template>

    <script type="application/dart">

    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'dart:html';

    import 'package:paper_elements/paper_input.dart';

    @CustomTag( 'paper-input-snippet' )
    class PaperInputSnippet extends PolymerElement
    {
      @observable String val = 'Tommy';
      String receiver = '';

      PaperInputSnippet.created() : super.created();

      void zoom( Event e, var detail )
      {
        print ( e.target );
        print ( val);
      }

      @override
      void attached()
      {
         super.attached();
         receiver = this.dataset['receiver'];
      }
    }

    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

However, changing the value of the paper-element does not print the new value, only the intialized value is printed.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong>

Comment: Is it allowed to inline dart code into a polymer element?

Comment: Maybe related to https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

An updated Polymer packages was just published that should fix this issue
see https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/bugs/-2f-TeaOoac
for more details.

You need to adjust your dependency constraint to get this update because its a development release

```
polymer: ">= 0.11.1-dev < 0.12.0"
```

**EDIT END**

There is an open issue for this code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19794

Until it is fixed, you can work around it by adding an `on-change` event handler:

```dart
<paper-input
    label="First" floatinglabel
    error="Invalid input"

    id="first_name"
    value='{{val}}'
    on-change='{{firstNameChangeHandler}}'
    >
  </paper-input>
```

```dart
  void firstNameChangeHandler() {
    val = ($['first_name'] as PaperInput).value;
  }
```

Comment: I followed instrunctions but when I ran the application I am getting an extra print out with the following | Kenny (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12).

Comment: I don't know what to do with your comment. Is this the whole error message? Try putting it into backticks ` `comment` `

Comment: Sorry. I use a print( val ); statement to see if the corrent value was being printed. Say I changed the default value from 'Tommy' to 'Kenny', then ran the app. The result is 'Kenny (http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/polymer/src/js/polymer/polymer.js:12)
Kenny'. Note that two 'Kenny' are printed, one alone as expected, the other with a reference to the polymer.js file.

Comment: I updated my answer because there seems to be an updates package available that should contain a fix for this issue.

Comment: for me on 0.12.0-dev

**<paper-input label="Project Path" inputValue="{{path}}" floatinglabel="true"></paper-input>
<paper-button label="Enhance Project at '{{path}}'"></paper-button>**

is still not working ?

Comment: I tried your code and for me it worked. I guess you expected the value to change **before** you leave the field (for example by pressing the tab key. If you want this behavior you need to change `value='{{val}}'>` to `inputValue='{{val}}'>`. `value` only changes when the input looses focus. `inputValue` reflects any change.